# Is this codes usage of document.location.toString() a DOM based XSS vulnerability?

Tags: xss, javascript, dom, jquery

I have come across the following JS code in multiple web applications. I think the reason for the popularity of this code snippet is [this accepted answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393768/1382832). Developers seem to be using this code a lot of switching menu tabs:

```
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

It basically reads from `document.location` and passes anything after a `#` to `$()` without any sanitation.

Even Burp Suite's Active Scanner reports it as a True Positive.

[image]

I've tried to exploit it, but it seems like a false positive to me. My hypothesis is that since JS is converting the URL as a String, any payload (including special chars) will be treated as a string.

Posting this here just to make sure if you guys can think of any other way to exploit it to cause a DOM based XSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This code snippet is vulnerable to XSS in jQuery prior to 1.9 (and in conjunction with the jQuery Migrate plugin).** Even now, it remains at least a bad practice.

The string argument to `$()` (shortcut for `jQuery()`) can be parsed either as a CSS selector or HTML code. Parsing the string as HTML implies an XSS vulnerability, just as `document.write()` would. On the other hand, injecting into a CSS selector is not directly exploitable in current browsers.

The [changelog](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring) for v1.9 explains how they changed the parsing behavior:

> Prior to 1.9, a string would be considered to be an HTML string if it
>   had HTML tags anywhere within the string. This has the potential to
>   cause inadvertent execution of code and reject valid selector strings.
>   As of 1.9, a string is only considered to be HTML if it starts with a
>   less-than ("<") character. The Migrate plugin can be used to restore
>   the pre-1.9 behavior.

Since the string from your snippet (`'.nav-tabs a[href="#' + <payload> + '"]'`) does not start with a `<`, you will not be able to inject your own code, when the page is running a current version of jQuery.

**However, you should still sanitize the output.** Sometimes, different modules (e.g. Wordpress plugins) come with their own jQuery library that might inadvertently override the newer version and reintroduce the legacy behavior. **A simple fix** would be to reject the string if `location.hash` is not alphanumeric or not contained in a list of predefined links.

Comment: This is corrent, but the site may also be vulnerable is a new version of jQuery is used together with jQuery-migrate, as jQuery-migrate reintroduced the same bugs:

Comment: For a demo see: http://research.insecurelabs.org/jquery/test/

Comment: @Erlend This fact is included in the quote from my answer. I'll try to emphasize it a little more.

Answer (score 1):

This was a pretty common XSS attack vector in jQuery, and can still affect sites using an outdated version of jQuery.

https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9521

Basically, if a string was an invalid selector, jQuery would assume it was HTML, and parse it as HTML. In [jQuery version 1.9](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring) jQuery mitigated this risk by only parsing a string as HTML if it started with `<`, so it should not be possible in modern jQuery.

Unfortunately many sites still use outdated versions of jQuery (including Stack Exchange), which enabled the [semi-recent WordPress XSS attack](https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/05/jetpack-and-twentyfifteen-vulnerable-to-dom-based-xss.html) due to a mistake in an HTML file for their font icon library.