# prevent dom based - xss from js file in mvc

Tags: xss, javascript, asp.net-mvc, dom

I'm using a free template as a front end in my application and the main javascript file came out as a high risk as it's vulnerable to a **dom based cross site scripting**.Is there a way to sanitize the javascript function inside a javascript file? I searched and i found a .net library "**System.Web.Security.AntiXss**" that works on the server side but what should i use in this js file?
the js file:

```
// Activate smooth scroll on page load with hash links in the url
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
      var initial_nav = window.location.hash;
      if ($(initial_nav).length) {
        var scrollto = $(initial_nav).offset().top - scrolltoOffset;
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: scrollto
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
      }
    }
  });
// Toggle .header-scrolled class to #header when page is scrolled
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('#header').addClass('header-scrolled');
    } else {
      $('#header').removeClass('header-scrolled');
    }
  });

  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('#header').addClass('header-scrolled');
  }

  // Back to top button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });

  $('.back-to-top').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    return false;
  });

  // jQuery counterUp
  $('[data-toggle="counter-up"]').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 1000
  });
 // Init AOS
  function aos_init() {
    AOS.init({
      duration: 1000,
      easing: "ease-in-out",
      once: true,
      mirror: false
    });
  }
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    aos_init();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is XSS possible with jQuery(location.hash)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177261/is-xss-possible-with-jquerylocation-hash)

Comment: In case it's not clear why I've marked that as a duplicate, it is because the part that your scanner has flagged as vulnerable is at the top where you take location.hash and pass it off to `$()` - which is exactly the same as `jQuery(location.hash)`.  Worst comes to worst you could always just remove this - it's job is to scroll nicely to a div, but the browser will always do that by default, just without a transition.

Comment: I removed it from the js file . I can't find a way around it but thank you though for explaining the source of the vulnerability here.

Comment: Probably a simple but safe work around would be to rely a bit more on native JavaScript instead of jQuery.  You won't have the same issues with, for instance, `document.getElementById()`.  You can even convert that to a jQuery element (I think), so something like this `$(document.getElementById(initial_nav)).length`, etc...